# ! Missing $ inserted when try to using superscript in matrix in beamer

Tags: beamer, matrices

I got the

> `! Missing $ inserted`

mistake message when I try to use superscript inside a matrix environment in `beamer`. The following is my code

```
\begin{frame}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \hat{\beta} \\ \hat{\beta}^{\dagger}
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
        U^\dagger & V^\dagger \\ U^\intercal & V^\intercal
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{frame}
```

I tried using `\begin{frame}[fragile]` but it didn't work.

Comment: You can't enter the `pmatrix` environment outside of math mode,  You either need `$` on each end of the `pmatrix` or `\[...\]`.delimiters.

Answer (score 4):

Converting my comment to an answer, LaTeX has a both text and math modes.  A number of commands intended for math mode use can only be invoked inside math mode.  Attempts to invoke them in text mode will receive a "missing $ inserted" error.

To enter math mode in LaTeX, one can enter inline math with dollar delimiters `$...$`.  Many argue a preferable way to do this is with the following delimiters: `\(...\)`.  For displaystyle math, which prints its content, centered, on its own line, use the delimiters `\[...\]`.

There are also several additional environments that will place one inside display math mode.  The `equation` environment does this.  Using the `amsmath` package, there is the `equation*` variant (that does not number the equation), and also a series of environments in the `align` family.

The `pmatrix` environment of `amsmath` is just such an envioronment that expects to already be in math mode, upon invocation.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \hat{\beta} \\ \hat{\beta}^{\dagger}
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
        U^\dagger & V^\dagger \\ U^\intercal & V^\intercal
    \end{pmatrix}
    \]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]